# Where is the SharePoint feature I just deployed?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Through Visual Studio 2010 I deployed a feature (which sets up a timer in the FeatureActivated event) to SharePoint.

The Site URL the project is pointing to is:

```
<code>
http://servername/sitename/
</code>
```

After I deploy I go into Central Admin and I see the Timer is there, yay.

However when I go into 'Site Settings' for 'sitename' then 'Manage site features' I do not see the feature listed.

Where is this feature? I want to be able to enable/disable it for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What scope is the feature?

- If it's a Farm scoped feature (scope = farm), you would need to check in Central Admin (System Settings -> Manage Farm Features)
- If it's a Web Application scoped feature (scope = webapplication), you would need to check in Central Admin (Application Management -> Manage Web Applications -> select Web Application -> Manage Features)
- If it's a Site Collection scoped feature (scope = site), you would need to check on the root of the site collection (Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site Collection Features)
- If it's a Site scoped feature (scope = web), you would need to check on the site (Site Settings -> Site Actions -> Manage Site Features)

What you've created sounds like a Timer job, so I'm guessing that it would be either a Farm or Web Application scoped feature.

If you open up the Feature in Visual Studio, there is a dropdown for scope which should tell you what you need to know.